# How separate and merge JSON array elements (for use in JQPlot)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON array that's been returned from an AJAX function. The array looks like this:

```
 {
    "date":[
        [
            "2015-05-29",
            "2015-05-12",
            "2015-04-30",
            "2015-03-30",
            "2015-02-27",
            "2015-02-26"
        ]
    ],
    "close":[
        [0,3,1,1,0,0]
    ],
    "high":[
        [1,3,2,1,0,1]
    ],
    "low":[
        [0,-1,0,-1,-1,-1]
    ]
}
```

I need to take the 'dates' and the 'close' items and blend them into something that will look like this, for JQPlot

```
var line1=[['2008-06-30 8:00AM',4], ['2008-7-30 8:00AM',6.5], ['2008-8-30 8:00AM',5.7], ['2008-9-30 8:00AM',9], ['2008-10-30 8:00AM',8.2]];
```

I figure I need to loop something like this but I'm not sure how to join the values into the new date format above?

```
s3 = obj["close"][0];
dates = obj["date"][0];

 for( var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++ ){
  //not sure what to put here
}
```

Comment: where is the `4, 6.5, 5.7, 9, 8.2` coming from? - oh, wait, your sample input and output data has absolutely no relation to each other

Comment: I agree the example is flawed but think OP explained clear enough in the post what the behavior is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

```
// the data object you get back from your ajax
var data = {"date":[["2015-05-29","2015-05-12","2015-04-30","2015-03-30","2015-02-27","2015-02-26"]],"close":[[0,3,1,1,0,0]],"high":[[1,3,2,1,0,1]],"low":[[0,-1,0,-1,-1,-1]]}

var time = " 8:00AM"

var dates = data.date[0]
var s3 = data.close[0]

// make sure the data is valid 
// (`dates` and `s3` must have the same length in order to join them)
if (dates.length !== s3.length) {
    throw new Error('oh no! the data is invalid')
}

var line1 = []

for(var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    line1.push([dates[i] + time, s3[i]])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.
Create a new array before the loop.

```
var result = new Array;
```

Then inside the loop you will add a new item to this array on every iteration.

```
result.push([dates[i], s3[i]]);
```

Now your result variable should hold your desired array.